# how to change the colour of tab in fireofx using addon?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

i'm developing a firefox addon. I'd like to change the colour of the current tab through my addon. How to do it??

Comment: have you tried doing anything?

Comment: ya,  tried to reverse engineer the addon Tab COlour to know how they do it:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place a .js file in your `chrome/content` folder and write a function like this:

```
// take a color and color the tab with it
setColor:function(tab, tabColor)
    {

    tab.style.setProperty('background-image','-moz-linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,.7),rgba('+tabColor+',.5),rgb('+tabColor+')),-moz-linear-gradient(rgb('+tabColor+'),rgb('+ tabColor+'))','important');

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about firefox plugin development but the color of the current tab is found at the browser.css (`chrome://browser/skin/browser.css`). There you will find this class `.tabbrowser-tab[selected="true"]:-moz-lwtheme` Changing the `color` property will change the color of the current tab. Changing the `color` property for `.tabbrowser-tab:-moz-lwtheme-darktext:not([selected="true"]), .tabs-newtab-button:-moz-lwtheme-darktext` will change the color for all other tabs.

Hope the above information to be helpful.